# Como quitar variables de una URL con htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Cuando se accede a URLs como las siguientes:

1. `https://midominio.net/page/61/?variable_hola=1&saludos=5148B409XXXXX677AB547FB3209AA8C8`
2. `https://midominio.net/page/20/?variable_hola=1&saludos=5148B409CD818677XX547FB3209AAAC9`

Quiero que se quiten los parámetros de búsqueda:

```
?variable_hola=1&saludos=5148B409CD8186UUAB547FB3208AA6
```

Tengo muchas URL de ese tipo, lo que varía es el código que está al final. Esos parámetros no los necesito, ya que esas variables no existen, no afectará que los elimine. Al usuario le aparece lo mismo, tenga o no los parámetros.

¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

Comment: ¿Y cómo pasarías esos parámetros entonces? ¿Dónde se enviaría esa información? ¿Como parte de la URL? ¿O podés modificarlos desde donde se generan para pasarlos por POST?

Comment: Esos parámetros no los necesito, ya que esas variables no existen, no afectará que los elimine.

Comment: Cuando un usuario entra a

`https://midominio.net/page/20/?variable_hola=1&saludos=5148B409CD818677XX547FB3209AAAC9` 

Le aparece lo mismo que:
 `https://midominio.net/page/20/`

Lo que quiero es que las urls que tienen los parametros se redirijan a las que no los tienen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si se accede a `page/###` (con `###` cualquier cantidad de dígitos) con parámetros de búsqueda, esta regla redirecciona a la misma URL pero sin los parámetros:

```py
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^(page/\d+/?)$ $1 [NC,QSD,R=302,L]
```

- El flag [`[QSD]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) ([*query string discard*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd)) justamente descarta los parámetros.
- Siempre que estés implementando una redirección, primero hay que hacer todas las pruebas con un 302. Solamente si estás muy seguro de que funciona, y de que no se van a cambiar en el futuro, recién ahí podrías cambiarlo a un 301. No antes, porque es peligroso: las redirecciones 301 son fuertemente cacheadas.

Comment: Hola, muy agradecido con tu respuesta, me ha funcionado a la perfección. No sabes lo agradecido que estoy con tu explicación.

Comment: Ahora me surjen dos dudas.

Me di cuenta que este código funciona siempre y cuando lo ponga al principio del htaccess, después de ese código tengo uno de wordpress, el cual es 

`# BEGIN WordPress  
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  
</IfModule>  
# END WordPress  `

¿No genera ningún error en el servidor poner el código antes?
¿Se puede cambiar el 302 por 301?

Comment: @ErickEstevez ningún problema, ya que sólo afecta a páginas con `page/##`, pero por una cuestión de orden lógico, yo pondría las últimas 2 líneas de mi respuesta justo después de la primera regla del `index.php`... No te funcionaría después de eso porque el resto de las líneas reescriben la URL y ya no podría coincidir.

Comment: @ErickEstevez agregué lo del 301 a la respuesta

Comment: He agregado las 2 últimas líneas del código debajo de la regla del index.php y sigue funcionando perfectamente. Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si te he entendido bien, lo que quieres es eliminar los parametros de la url.
Entiendes por lo tanto que esas variables ya no serán accesibles.
Tu .htaccess podría ser algo así:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page/([0-9])/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://midominio.net/page/$1 [R=302,NC]
```

Comment: Hola, estoy probando ese código en el htaccess, pero no me funciona, no hace nada, lo que quiero es que todo lo que tenga esos parámetros se redirijan a los que no lo tienen.